# CKAN to store and publish RDFS

Tags: dataset, metadata, ckan, rdfs

in my job we have CKAN for store and publish datasets.

I am looking for a metadata registry solution,

Is possible store rdf schema data on CKAN and share it?

I read about /ckanext-dcat extension but I am not
sure if it support RDFS.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score -1):

Sure. You can link to any URL in CKAN, including a RDF Schema file.

ckanext-dcat is something else - it converts your metadata to RDF's representation of it i.e. DCAT.